# Feature Layers for Subsets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, geoprocessing

I need to create a subset of data based off their distance from particular points in ArcMap. Is it possible to create Feature layers that have a defined buffer, that only show data within that buffer? Or must I create a physical subset of the data based my buffered selection?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field to your feature class and attribute based on what buffer they fall in.  Then you would be able to query the feature class for each buffer distance.

Comment: I can't add attributes to data

Comment: Would it be best to make Feature layers, then save as layers?

Comment: If I add a field to my Point feature class(the one I'm buffering), then what do I do?

Comment: It depends on the details of what exactly it is you want to do. As I understand it, you have FC1 (the point FC) and FC2.  Add a field to FC2, call it DIST_TO_FC1.  Make a 100ft buffer of FC1, select by location the features in FC2 that intersect this buffer.  Calculate the Field DIST_TO_FC1 for those selected features as "100 ft."  Repeat for other distances as necessary.  You tagged this post with 'python' - if you are looking for an arcpy script then start looking at the docs for Buffer, Make Feature Layer, Add Field, Calcualte Field...